# What is the recommended way of shutting down Corda nodes on a network?

Tags: corda

For a set of nodes running on a network, what is the recommended way to gracefully shut them down versus simply killing the processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to deploy your nodes following the instructions here - https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html

This way, in Linux for example, you could:

Start a node with

```
>systemctl start corda
```

And stop a node with

```
>systemctl stop corda
```

Likewise, with Windows, you would run Corda as a Windows service and stop it as such.

Another thing to keep in mind when shutting down nodes is the state of any in-flight flows. Corda provides a *draining mode* which can be read about [here](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-node.html) in the Draining Mode section. This can be enabled via RPC, see the docs [here](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/set-flows-draining-mode-enabled.html)